# Wordpress Custom Post Types Redirect Issue

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-post-type

When using pretty links with Custom Post Types UI plugin i receive a constant redirect when i preview custom posts i.e people/mark-james. Does anybody have a clue why this is happening? I am using this in conjunction with Advanced Permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

Try resaving permalinks in settings > permalinks. I believe just visting that page cleans stuff.